# How can i adjust the size of the design tab in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am using Android Studio since a few days, and latelly i got a problem
My design tab adjusted his size and now i can't see my whole application because it is to much to the left.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `SHIFT+F12` to reset the IDE view

Hope it works

Comment: I let someone else on my laptop he wanted to try if he was able to fix it but he accidently pressed the store current layout as default so that won't work for me...